# Concatenate 2 dataframes (update) aggregating by sum

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, concatenation, insert-update

I have 2 dataframes, *df1* and *df2*. Dataframe *df2* must be concatenated with *df1* with values in column 'bricks' which are not in *df1* and if column value exists then update the volume data by adding the *df1* 'volume' with the *df2* 'volume'. The result should be sorted by 'bricks'.

Example:

```
df1 = [
    {'bricks':-3, 'volume':50},
    {'bricks':-2, 'volume':20},
    {'bricks':-1, 'volume':30}
]

df2 = [
    {'bricks':-1, 'volume':10},
    {'bricks':-2, 'volume':0},
    {'bricks':-3, 'volume':60},
    {'bricks':-4, 'volume':60},
    {'bricks':-5, 'volume':60},
]
```

Expected result:

```
df1 = [
    {'bricks':-5, 'volume':60},
    {'bricks':-4, 'volume':60},
    {'bricks':-3, 'volume':110},
    {'bricks':-2, 'volume':20},
    {'bricks':-1, 'volume':40}    
]
```

Comment: You should tell which type of dataframes do you use. Pandas, PySpark, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('bricks').sum().reset_index()

    bricks  volume
0   -5  60
1   -4  60
2   -3  110
3   -2  20
4   -1  40
```

Comment: Click on the checkbox under the lower triangle in my answer. That is my acceptance of your answer. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you worked with PySpark.

```py
df = df1.union(df2).groupby('bricks').agg(F.sum('volume').alias('volume')).orderBy('bricks')
df.show()
#     +------+------+
#     |bricks|volume|
#     +------+------+
#     |    -5|    60|
#     |    -4|    60|
#     |    -3|   110|
#     |    -2|    20|
#     |    -1|    40|
#     +------+------+
```